# Not able to start hive metastore after postgres upgradation from 9 to 12

Tags: hive

I was using Apache hive 1.2.1 with postgres 9 as remote metastore. It was working fine with postgres version 9. Getting result set closed error after postgres upgraded from 9 to 12 version whenever trying to start hive metastore. Error is as under:

```
javax.jdo.JDODataStoreException: This ResultSet is closed.
        at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.NucleusJDOHelper.getJDOExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJDOHelper.java:451)
        at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.getDataStoreConnection(JDOPersistenceManager.java:2259)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreDirectSql.getProductName(MetaStoreDirectSql.java:168)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreDirectSql.determineDbType(MetaStoreDirectSql.java:159)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreDirectSql.<init>(MetaStoreDirectSql.java:121)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.initialize(ObjectStore.java:295)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.setConf(ObjectStore.java:258)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:73)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.<init>(RawStoreProxy.java:57)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.getProxy(RawStoreProxy.java:66)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.newRawStore(HiveMetaStore.java:593)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMS(HiveMetaStore.java:571)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB(HiveMetaStore.java:624)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:461)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:66)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:72)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:5756)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:5751)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.startMetaStore(HiveMetaStore.java:5984)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.main(HiveMetaStore.java:5909)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212) NestedThrowablesStackTrace: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: This ResultSet is closed.
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.checkClosed(AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.java:2852)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.setFetchSize(AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.java:1875)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Statement.createResultSet(Jdbc4Statement.java:37)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement$StatementResultHandler.handleResultRows(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:221)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1853)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:255)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:561)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:405)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.execSQLUpdate(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:382)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.getTransactionIsolation(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:904)
        at com.jolbox.bonecp.ConnectionHandle.getTransactionIsolation(ConnectionHandle.java:825)
        at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl$ManagedConnectionImpl.getConnection(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:444)
        at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl$ManagedConnectionImpl.getXAResource(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:378)
        at org.datanucleus.store.connection.ConnectionManagerImpl.allocateConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:328)
        at org.datanucleus.store.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.getConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:94)
        at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager.getNucleusConnection(RDBMSStoreManager.java:1357)
        at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.getDataStoreConnection(JDOPersistenceManager.java:2245)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreDirectSql.getProductName(MetaStoreDirectSql.java:168)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreDirectSql.determineDbType(MetaStoreDirectSql.java:159)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreDirectSql.<init>(MetaStoreDirectSql.java:121)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.initialize(ObjectStore.java:295)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.setConf(ObjectStore.java:258)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:73)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.<init>(RawStoreProxy.java:57)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.getProxy(RawStoreProxy.java:66)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.newRawStore(HiveMetaStore.java:593)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMS(HiveMetaStore.java:571)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB(HiveMetaStore.java:624)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:461)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:66)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:72)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:5756)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:5751)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.startMetaStore(HiveMetaStore.java:5984)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.main(HiveMetaStore.java:5909)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212) Exception in thread "main" javax.jdo.JDODataStoreException: This ResultSet is closed.
        at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.NucleusJDOHelper.getJDOExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJDOHelper.java:451)
        at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.getDataStoreConnection(JDOPersistenceManager.java:2259)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreDirectSql.getProductName(MetaStoreDirectSql.java:168)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreDirectSql.determineDbType(MetaStoreDirectSql.java:159)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreDirectSql.<init>(MetaStoreDirectSql.java:121)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.initialize(ObjectStore.java:295)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.setConf(ObjectStore.java:258)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:73)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.<init>(RawStoreProxy.java:57)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.getProxy(RawStoreProxy.java:66)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.newRawStore(HiveMetaStore.java:593)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMS(HiveMetaStore.java:571)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB(HiveMetaStore.java:624)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:461)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:66)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:72)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:5756)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:5751)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.startMetaStore(HiveMetaStore.java:5984)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.main(HiveMetaStore.java:5909)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212) NestedThrowablesStackTrace: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: This ResultSet is closed.
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.checkClosed(AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.java:2852)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.setFetchSize(AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.java:1875)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Statement.createResultSet(Jdbc4Statement.java:37)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement$StatementResultHandler.handleResultRows(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:221)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1853)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:255)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:561)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:405)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.execSQLUpdate(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:382)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.getTransactionIsolation(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:904)
        at com.jolbox.bonecp.ConnectionHandle.getTransactionIsolation(ConnectionHandle.java:825)
        at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl$ManagedConnectionImpl.getConnection(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:444)
        at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl$ManagedConnectionImpl.getXAResource(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:378)
        at org.datanucleus.store.connection.ConnectionManagerImpl.allocateConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:328)
        at org.datanucleus.store.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.getConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:94)
        at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager.getNucleusConnection(RDBMSStoreManager.java:1357)
        at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.getDataStoreConnection(JDOPersistenceManager.java:2245)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreDirectSql.getProductName(MetaStoreDirectSql.java:168)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreDirectSql.determineDbType(MetaStoreDirectSql.java:159)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreDirectSql.<init>(MetaStoreDirectSql.java:121)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.initialize(ObjectStore.java:295)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.setConf(ObjectStore.java:258)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:73)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.<init>(RawStoreProxy.java:57)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.getProxy(RawStoreProxy.java:66)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.newRawStore(HiveMetaStore.java:593)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMS(HiveMetaStore.java:571)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB(HiveMetaStore.java:624)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:461)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:66)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:72)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:5756)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:5751)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.startMetaStore(HiveMetaStore.java:5984)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.main(HiveMetaStore.java:5909)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
```

Have tried using latest postgres jdbc jar but not worked. For testing purpose I tried to connect postgres version 9, it worked but as soon as tried to connect version 12 of postgres error appearing.

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Please take the [tour], edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. Also see [ask].